# Could the Elder Wand have healed Neville's Parents?

Tags: harry-potter, deathly-hallows

We know from the end of *Deathly Hallows* that Harry becomes the master of the Elder Wand, and uses it to repair his own broken wand. Until this point, it has been impossible to repair broken wands, and that the wand *could* be repaired shows that it is not limited by the traditional boundaries and limitations of magic.

Could Harry have used the Elder Wand to heal Mr and Mrs Longbottom? I do not think this is referred to specifically in canon but I would like to know if any likely conclusions can be drawn based on any precedents already set by the Elder Wand or healers.

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about a potential possibility.  We don't allow "What if...x" questions that have no way to be answered definitively.

Comment: If everyone who ever asked a question knew it could be answered definitively, they probably wouldn't need to ask it.

Comment: See http://www.xkcd.com/102/ .  Also, I don't think it can, because the Elder Wand is useful only for arcane magic, and healing requires divine magic.

Comment: *I would like to know if any likely conclusions can be drawn based on any precedents already set by the Elder Wand or healers.* This seems like a straightforward fact-based question.

Comment: A muggle brain hospital would have healed them. But, wizards are arrogant snobs who couldn't send their patiences to muggle hospital.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

**I would guess not.** Or at least, not with the state of Healing knowledge in *Deathly Hallows*.

The Elder Wand can reinforce existing spells. We don’t see it performing truly impossible or unknowable feats of magic.

In the case of Harry’s wand, there was already a spell for repairing objects: Reparo. While an ordinary wand isn’t powerful enough to repair Harry’s broken one, the superior strength of the Elder Wand overcomes this barrier.

Everything in canon suggests that the Longbottoms’s condition is permanent. Magic cannot cure them, not can it bring about any meaningful improvement in their condition. Their minds seem broken beyond repair, so you can’t just cast the “repair mind” spell at them with the Elder Wand and rely on its superior abilities. No such spell exists.

Also worth noting that Dumbledore had the Elder Wand for years, and either never tried, or was never successful, in using the wand to cure Neville’s parents. His knowledge of magic is greater than anybody else, and even he couldn’t do it.

Comment: However, Ollivander had already said that a wand that has suffered as much damage as Harry's is beyond repair. If only a stronger Reparo spell could fix it, Ollivander would have known, given his level of expertise.

Comment: ollivander also didn't believe the elder wand existed so hes stup- uh- an unreliable source when it comes to elder wand ability. the problem with nevells parents is that they are not cursed, of physically impaired in anyway. They literally had a mental break down due to the torture they endured. it is up to the brain itself whether it will come out of that or not. now on the other hand lockheart may actually be able to have his brain fixed, as we know it was the direct result of a spell. again maybe not, but his is clearly spell damage induced.

Comment: The rest of the answer is fine but Dumbledore was a right hard ass, he wouldn't give away having the elder wand "just" to heal some of his closest allies. Also it would ruin Neville's preparations as a potential chose one if his parents were ok.

Comment: Isn't Episkey an existing spell that cures things? So shouldn't the Elder Wand be able to cure Neville's parents by "reinforcing" it?

Comment: Episkey only cures physical wounds, not mental ones. So, no, it wouldn't work at all with Neville's parents.